# Ergonomic way of only adding a new object to a map if it doesn't exist?

Tags: javascript, performance

I am developing a game where it is very often that I wish to perform the following operation:

```
if (!buffs.has("shielding")) {
  buffs.add(new ShieldingBuff(50)); // 50 is the shield amount
}
```

where `buffs` type is `Map<string, Buff>`.

I thought to wrap it in a helper function like so:

```
function addBuff(buffType, buff) {
  if (!this.buffs.has(buffType) {
    this.buffs.add(buff);
  }
}
```

and then calling it like this:

```
addBuff("shielding", new ShieldingBuff(50));
```

But the problem with that is that in 99% of cases the buff will already be applied, and this incurs a significant garbage collection cost, since we're allocating a `ShieldingBuff` object regardless of whether or not we actually need it.

I was thinking about maybe using short-circuiting somehow, but I cannot think of an ergonomic way of doing it. The best I could do is come up with something like this:

```
buffs.add(!buffs.has("shielding") && new ShieldingBuff(50));
```

which works to avoid the allocation in the case the buff is already applied.. but is still rather verbose. Ideally I would be able to encapsulate the `has` check into the helper function somehow, but I can't see a way to do that while maintaining the short-circuiting trick to avoid the allocation in the majority case where the buff is already applied and nothing need be done.

My worry is that if I have to remember to call the `has` check every time, eventually I'll forget and it will lead to a bug. I would like to avoid that if possible.

Comment: There’s the [`Map.prototype.emplace` proposal](//github.com/tc39/proposal-upsert).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something that has a *bit* of overhead but probably not as much as `ShieldingBuff` would be a simple function that, when called, creates one:

```
addBuff("shielding", () => new ShieldingBuff(50));
```

```
function addBuff(buffType, makeBuff) {
  if (!this.buffs.has(buffType) {
    this.buffs.add(makeBuff());
  }
}
```

Another approach would be to refactor your code so you don't have to repeat `'shielding'` and `shieldingBuff` - instead, use an object or Map for the buffs instead of having multiple standalone variables.

For example, with an object like

```
const buffs = {
  Shielding: function() {
    // code of ShieldingBuff here
  }
  // ...
}
```

Then you can do

```
addBuff("shielding", 50)
```

where, if the condition is fulfilled, `addBuff` capitalizes the first letter, and passes the 50 to the constructor when needed, using bracket notation to find the constructor on the `buffs` object.

Comment: Yeah, I thought of a factory-approach as well, and was going to include it in the original question, but didn't want to risk making the post any longer than it already was. The fact that that was your immediate intuition as well leads more credence to the idea that this may be the best solution. I suppose I could declare a data file full of pre-allocated factory functions for creating various buffs. In any case, I was hoping there'd be a simpler way, but if no other answer comes along then I'll likely accept this one.

Comment: Yeah, your edit seems like a very good approach. Thank you for the answer. I was thinking something along these lines so the fact that this was your immediate intuition (as stated) gives me peace of mind with regard to the correctness of the solution.